# Ajax jquery calls to get list of all project

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira-rest-api

Iam using JIRA to get the list of all project.I had used Ajax calls to get the list and populate in html.

```
<html><td><select  id="projectsList" class="textFld"></select></td></html>
```

The project list was not populated.
the url was working correctly if i test it directly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ getAllProjectsList(); });  



function getAllProjectsList() {
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://server/issues/rest/api/2/project",

}, function(status, projectsList) {
    var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
    if (status === 'success') {
        $.each(projectsLst, function(index, item) {
            htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Error while retrieving projects list from JIRA service.");
    }
    $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
});
```

}

Comment: are you getting JS error? Can you please check browser's console and confirm that.

Comment: No errors in console..

Comment: Any help on this....

Answer (score 0):

I think its cross domain  issue...

Try with $.getJSON() method instead of $.ajax(), I am not sure in your case it working or not.

```
$.getJSON("http://server/issues/rest/api/2/project",function(projectsList) {
    var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
    if (status === 'success') {
        $.each(projectsLst, function(index, item) {
            htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Error while retrieving projects list from JIRA service.");
    }
    $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
});
```

Comment: Or just give the crossDomain as true.
Refer this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Try consoling the outputs so that you get a better idea of whats being actualy retrieved.

Comment: If, this not working then Jira api not allowed cross domain through ajax request. For alternate, you have to make one script on server that get data from Jira api using CURL and fetch response and echo that. and then call that script through ajax.

Comment: It  was working:  function getAllProjectsList() {
 $.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : "http:/server/issues/rest/api/2/project",
    
    success: function(projectsList){
     var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
     $.each(projectsList, function(index, item) {
      htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
     
     });
   $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
    }
  });
}

Comment: @AnushaGonugunta, how its was worked, my creating script or direct request from ajax?

Comment: I had used Ajax   ' $.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : "http://issues/rest/api/2/project",
    
    success: function(projectsList){
     var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
     $.each(projectsList, function(index, item) {
      htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
      });
     $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
       }          
});
}'

Comment: are you sure it worked. url should be like this: https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/project. I don't know how you got response with your url "https://jira.company.com/issues/rest/api/2/project"

Comment: Yes it is working.....i got list of project and list of user and issues...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "server/issues/rest/api/2/project",

      success: function(projectsList){
                var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
                $.each(projectsList, function(index, item) {
                    htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
                    });
                $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
                 }              });}
```

Now i got the project list.Based on project selected how to get user list.